# Formatting XML for easy reading

Tags: c#, xml, .net-2.0

I have a list of file names and each file has a checksum.  What is the best way about organizing this data in an xml file?  So far I have:

```
<tables>
    <table name="test1.txt">"KMDalk4lsmxf#lsfjs_akmf3"</table>
    <table name="test2.txt">"asd6o9iASla0gbd#0saaj234"</table>
    <table name="test3.txt">"S9rk2jalkjf93klsa+jmskl2"</table>
    <table name="test4.txt">"aj54oislkaoi309aSWpoa2JD"</table>
</tables>
```

Now, using XMLReader I want to be able to find a table by name only and then return the checksum.  How do I go about this?  Is it best to use attributes or elements for file names?

Comment: Any reason you're quoting the checksums?

Comment: I need them as strings.  I'm going to guess I don't need to quote them..

Comment: You don't. Everything from the doc is intrinsically a string.

Comment: Do you need only help on formatting, or `XmlReader` sample too?

Comment: No I think I can figure it out.  I guess I just wasn't sure how I should store the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store checksum in attribute, like this:

```
<tables>
    <table name="test1.txt" checksum="KMDalk4lsmxf#lsfjs_akmf3"/>
    <table name="test2.txt" checksum="asd6o9iASla0gbd#0saaj234"/>
    <table name="test3.txt" checksum="S9rk2jalkjf93klsa+jmskl2"/>
    <table name="test4.txt" checksum="aj54oislkaoi309aSWpoa2JD"/>
</tables>
```

It will be more consistent.

But in fact there's no much difference, most performance will go into finding a node with matching `name` anyway.